# How to create a parametrable sql request for creating table with many fields

Tags: java, sql

Here's what I propose, but the problem I will have `,` in the end. For example I will have:

```
create table(field 1 varchar(50) not null,field 2 varchar(45) not null,);
```

My question is how to remove the last `,`???

```
String req = "CREATE TABLE " + db.getTable_Name() + " (";
for (int i = 0; i < db.getColumns_number(); i++) {
    req += db.getField() + " " + db.getType() + "(" + db.getSize() + ")" + " " + db.getNullabilité () + ",";
}

req += ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use the below code

```
if(i<db.getColumns_number()){
    //add ","
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String req="CREATE TABLE " +db.getTable_Name()+" (";
         for(int i=0;i<db.getColumns_number();i++){  
             req+= db.getField()+" "+db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +" "+db.getNullabilité();
             //add comma until is not last column
             if (i < (db.getColumns_number()-1)) {
                req+=",";
             }
         } 

req+=")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply switch how you add your comma. For example:

```
String req = "CREATE TABLE " + db.getTable_Name() + " (";
for (int i = 0; i < db.getColumns_number(); i++) {
    req += (i > 0 ? ", " : "") + db.getField() + " " + db.getType() + "(" + db.getSize() + ")" + " " + db.getNullabilité();
}

req += ")";
```

This will check whether we are after the first index. If we are after the first index, we add a comma to the start. If it is the first index, we add nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last , is quite easy. Without regexp:

```
String s = "create table(field 1 varchar(50) not null,field 2 varchar(45) not null,);";
int n = s.lastIndexOf(',');
System.out.println(s.substring(0, n) + s.substring(n+1));
```

Result:

create table(field 1 varchar(50) not null,field 2 varchar(45) not null);

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<db.getColumns_number();i++){  
       if(i!=0){
          req+=", ";
       }
       req+= db.getField()+" "+db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +" "+db.getNullabilité();
       //req+= ((i!=0)?", ":"") + db.getField()+" "+db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +" "+db.getNullabilité();
       //req+= db.getField()+" "+db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +" "+db.getNullabilité() + ((i != (db.getColumns_number()-1))?",":"");
 }
```

Comment: but in the end  you will have a ","  ?

Comment: @ChawqiHajar No because this adds the `,` at the start of the column description not at the end and it doesn't do that for the first column description.